# How do I get Glibc >= 2.16.0?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, pidgin

I know there are already built packages for Pidgin. I need to build Pidgin so I can build plug-ins.

I need Glibc >= 2.16.0. Unfortunately, I get stuck in an endless dependency loop. I need libgtk2.0-dev and libglibc-devel which apparently needs libpango1.0-dev. libpango1.0-dev needs libcairo2-dev. libcairo2-dev needs libcairo2, libcairo-gobject2, and libpixman-1-dev.

Then it says "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." How can this be true if I ran `sudo apt-get install -f` and it spat out the following:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pidgin-libnotify indicator-status-provider-pidgin liblaunchpad-integration1
  libodbc1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

I don't want to remove them. The system may not need them, but I still want them.

Sometimes I think apt has a dependency problem, not the packages. However, that is beyond the scope of my question.

So again, how do I get these dependencies without using dpkg and possibly introducing foreign sources which will inevitably break my system?

Comment: Try using Synaptic Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, glibc is not something you can just upgrade.
However, you can just use "pbuilder" and PPAs to have your stuff built.
Or even VirtualBox with a simple Ubuntu server.

For more information on Pbuilder and PPAs, check the [Packaging Guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/).